# Find polygons which are intersecting / touches with defined polygon

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I have a polygon and I would like to find all polygons from the table `planet_osm_polygon` which my polygon lies in or touches. I tried to use `st_intersects` function but it doesn't work as I would expect. See my command below..

```sql
WITH bbox AS
    (SELECT st_transform(st_makeenvelope(9.3183939, 48.8282700, 9.5182078, 48.9375419, 4326), 3857) AS geom)
SELECT p.*
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM planet_osm_polygon WHERE boundary IS NOT NULL AND admin_level IS NOT NULL) p,
     bbox b
WHERE st_intersects(p.way, b.geom);
```

It seems that by my query I receive only polygons which are crossing my `bbox` (see image below) however I would need to receive also polygons which are not just crossing my `bbox` but also polygons which are completely around my `bbox`.

[image]

Comment: can you clarify which of the polygons in your image are not selected that you would like to select?

Comment: @IanTurton The all polygons on the image are selected (these are counties and regions) but I would like to select also country which my `bbox` lies in -> this country is not on the image but you can imagine it as a bit polygon which is around of all of selected polygons.

Comment: It should be here if it's in your table and it's a valid polygon. Are you sure that you have your country polygon ? I know that when you import osm data of a country from geofabrik for exemple the boundary for the country is not in it because it's this boundary that was used to cut the data. Try to list polygon with admin_level=2

Comment: @robinloche You are right. This polygon is not presented there. Probably somebody accidentially deleted this polygon from the database, because I already worked with it before. Thanks for the hint!